# "Failed to instantiate module" при подключение ng-app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Подключаю AngularJS 1.4.2 и директиву `ng-app="test"` в проект. Отключил всё кроме AngularJS. Получаю такую ошибку:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module test
>    due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'test' is not available! You
>    either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>    a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>    argument

подобная ошибка вылазит если запустить на codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPJNOG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня используется require и поэтому это нужно было делать так

```
var angular =  require("angular");
var app = angular.module( "test", [] );
angular.bootstrap( document, ['test']);
```

Пример использования с require

```
require( [ 'angular', 'require' ], function ( ) {

 var angular =  require("angular");
 var app = angular.module( "XXX", [ 'ngResource' ] );

 require ( "../XXFactory" ) ( app );
 require ( "../XXFactory" ) ( app );
 require( "../XXController" ) ( app );
} )
```

Comment: Разве он не асинхронно скрипт запрашивает?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Асинхронно, но у меня еще есть require который gulp использует для сборки, и я просто затупил)

Comment: Но `angular.module` ты вызываешь сразу, не дожидаясь загрузки?

Comment: @Qwertiy, там получается что код в котором вызывается angular.module, ждет загрузку всей страницы (domcontentloaded) и потом вызывает этот код и поэтому ошибка так как ангуляр тоже работает с этим событием.

Comment: Так он не должен ждать. Ждать сам ангуляр будет, а модуль надо создать сразу. Но я не понимаю, почему в этом коде ты делаешь `require` и _сразу_ используешь ангуляр.

Comment: @Qwertiy смотри, нам нужно подключи модули мы делаем так     
`[пример кода добавил в ответ]`           
require загружает модули и кеширует, учитывая что обычно получается около 5+ модулей, то через  параметры не айс их юзать)

Comment: Ага, понял. Я просто думал, что тот вызов require - это именно загрузка модуля.

Answer (score 1):

А сам модуль кто создавать будет? Пушкин?

```
angular.module("test", []);
```

Comment: создавал и модуль,  я только что подумал, модуль должен быть создан до загрузги страницы?

Comment: @cyber_ua, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVrEoV - ошибки нет.

Comment: Александр вроде с AngularJS особо не работал. Надо будет поинтересоваться у него.

Comment: @Qwertiy , я добавил модуль, но у меня он был изначально в коде и с ним выдавало ошибку, он подключался после загрузке всей страницы.
И короче я кажется понял свою ошибку нужно использовать бутсрапинг